# Knockout JS if condition not being recognized

Tags: html, knockout.js

I have the following knockout and HTML:

```
                <table>
                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.selectedGroup().services">
                        <!-- ko if: ($index() % 2 === 0) -->
                        <tr>
                            <td data-bind="text:1">
                            </td>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        <!-- ko ifnot: ($index() % 2 === 0) -->
                            <td data-bind="text: 0"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

I only get the 1s, but no 0s.  I have 5 items in my array

I should be displaying

```
1 0
1 0
1
```

but I only have

```
1
1
1
```

any ideas?

Comment: i am not sure your containerless if condition is valid .

Comment: This fiddle reproduces the problem described: http://jsfiddle.net/cy2b6vuu/

Comment: Jamiec, thanks for your reply, but you copied my code wrong.  You placed the `<tr>` in the wrong place.  Try again and you will see the issue

Comment: @DJBurb - I think you're referring to my first comment (now deleted) I have in fact reproduced the issue

Comment: Cool.  I can't see why this doesn't work

Comment: No, me either. It renders the second column but does not appear to evaluate the bindings. I think I have a workaround for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach

http://jsfiddle.net/L46wjw7n/

```
<table>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.services">
        <!-- ko if: ($index() % 2 === 0) -->
        <tr>
            <!-- ko with: $root.services[$index()] -->
            <td data-bind="text:$data"></td>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko with: $root.services[$index()+1] -->
            <td data-bind="text:$data"></td>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

It works by looking ahead in your array for the next item and then rendering the row on each second item.

I think it would be better to model this in your viewmodel though, this is a tortured solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight issue with placement of container less if conditions

You written if/ifnot condition its like if/else so you get output either 0 or 1 for each row not both

```
               <table>
                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.selectedGroup().services">

                        <tr>
                        <!-- ko if: ($index() % 2 === 0) -->
                            <td data-bind="text:1">
                            </td>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        <!-- ko ifnot: ($index() % 2 === 0) -->
                            <td data-bind="text: 0"></td>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/z9u5xyx0/)**

Comment: Yeah, that shows all 5, but it won't work that way because the values to show as separate rows for each value.  

I need the values to show 2 per row.

Comment: 1 0 1 0 1 is this the output you looking for ? fiddle attached check

Comment: The fiddle answer is showing all of the values. This is true, but the values should have the 1s in one column and the 0s in another column. Check my original post for an example on how it should look

Comment: yes, but your code is not taking in account for the mod not equaling to 0

Comment: yes it doesn't for a matter of fact . as i mentioned in my answer your are doing like `if/else` both `tds`  wont execute at a time until unless you have single condition on top of both tds

Comment: no they aren't meant to execute on the same loop around.  It should be an either/or. This is based off the index of the array.  So for each loop around in the `foreach` it should hit only one of those conditions

Answer (score 0):

Knockout does appear to be doing something weird here, but to be honest this way of fudging a 2 column layout using if/ifnot bindings to conditionally render the opening and closing `<tr>` nodes seems a bit over-complicated.

What you could do is to rework your flat list into the appropriate rows/columns using a computed observable:

```
 this.services = ["bar","foo","bar","foo","bar","foo","bar","foo","bar","foo","bar","foo","bar","foo"];

this.serviceRows = ko.computed(function(){
     var result = [],
    row,
    colLength = 2;

    //loop through items and push each item to a row array that gets pushed to the final result
    for (var i = 0, j = this.services.length; i < j; i++) {
        if (i % colLength === 0) {
            if (row) {
              result.push(row);     
            }
            row = [];
        }
        row.push(this.services[i]);
    }

    //push the final row  
    if (row) {
        result.push(row);
    }

    return result;
}, this);
```

And then render the template in a much more straight forward manner:

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: serviceRows">
       <tr data-bind="foreach: $data">
            <td data-bind="text: ($index() % 2)"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/k773qf9o/